# want to see information in popup without textbox

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

i have information in text box but when i click button(show) then i  want to show information in popup without text box how to do it?``

```
      <tr>
      <td>
      <?php echo $i; ?>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $value['fullname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['group_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['institute_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['dept_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['library_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['role']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['status']; ?></td>
      <td><?php if($edit_allowed) { ?>
      <a href= "<?php echo $this->baseUrl().'/user/eid/'.$value['user_id']; ?>"
      data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addhod">
      <button  class="btn btn-primary"> View profile</button>
      </a>  
      <?php } 
       ?>          
      </tr>
```

Comment: If you want to a show popup then your modal header,body,footer part should be in the same page.first let me clear that you want a modal on the same page or in a different one.Clear about this anchor tag you have written it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this can help you.apply the code in your coding.hope this will help you

```
<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to get informataion in the textbox and display it as you want.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="info" id="info" value="information" >
<a href="#" onclick="showMsg();return false;">click me</a>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
 function showMsg(){
  var = $("#info").val();
  alert(var);
 }
</script>
```